# Similar content not handled as similar in testcase

Tags: php, json, phpunit

I've been implementing a `JsonExporter` and since `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` was added the testcase cannot be fixed anymore. `phpunit` still thinks there is a difference in the output, but it actually isn't:

```
// code of the testcase
$exporter->export($outFile, array(
    'key.a' => 'aaa',
    'key.b' => 'bbb',
    'key.c' => 'ccc',
));
$expectedContent = <<<EOL
{
    "key.a": "aaa",
    "key.b": "bbb",
    "key.c": "ccc"
}
EOL;
$this->assertEquals($expectedContent, file_get_contents($outFile));
```

Have been testing with multiple delimiters, `<<<C` and `PHP_EOL` also don't fix the testcase. The testcase always fails but there is no difference in the output:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 '{
     "key.a": "aaa",
     "key.b": "bbb",
     "key.c": "ccc"
 }'
```

How can we make this testcase pass?

**Edit:** the `Exporter` only does a simple `json_encode`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function export($file, $translations)
{
    $bytes = file_put_contents($file, json_encode($translations, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    return ($bytes !== false);
}
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code for replicate your scenario?

Comment: @Matteo did add the export function, but don't think that'll be related because it's just a simple `json_encode` that is saved to a file.

Comment: very strange, you code and test pass on my env... (PHP 5.5.16)

Comment: We have `5.4.45-1~dotdeb+7.1` over here. Other test are just fine, so I have no other clue.

Comment: sorry, i don't know how help you... if is an environment problem try with a trivial github project and configure a travis with various php version/configuration

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit implements some assertions that will compare JSON data:

- [assertJsonFileEqualsJsonFile()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertJsonFileEqualsJsonFile)
- [assertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile)
- [assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString)

These will compare the data structure, not the JSON string format.

Comment: That solved it for the test, but what if I want to actually test the formatting? The format also should be okay, because that's used in translation files.

Comment: That was not stated in your question so we could not know. Anyway, what I'd try is split the JSON strings by the newline character, and compare both arrays. If there is any difference, PHPUnit will tell you which line differs, as it does when comparing arrays.